# Store documents from firestore in list

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to retrieve documents from collection called "Org" and store it in list to display in the dropdownmenu, but the list returns `[Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot', Instance of 'QueryDocumentSnapshot']` and thus i get following error:

```
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => DropdownMenuItem<dynamic>)
```

This is the code i implemented:

```
void organisation() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Org").get();
    final List<DocumentSnapshot> list = querySnapshot.docs;
    print(list);
    list.forEach((data) => print(data));
  }
@override
  initState() {
    
    
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    organisation();
    
  
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is how i implemented dropdownmenu:

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
                          validator: (value) => value == "Select" ? 'Field required' : null,
                          value: _selectorg,
                                          onChanged: (val) => setState(() => _selectorg = val),
                                          
                                          items: list.map(
                                            (item) {
                                              return DropdownMenuItem(
                                                child: Text('$item'),
                                                value: item,
                                              );
                                            },
                                          ).toList(),
                                      hint: Text(
                                          "SELECT ORGANISATION",
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                                      
                      ),
```

Comment: where are u calling `organisation()`?

Comment: in initState() .

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
@override
  initState() {
    
    
    
  
    super.initState();
Firebase.initializeApp();
    organisation();
    
  }
```

And,

Declare your list outside the function

```
final List<DocumentSnapshot> list;

void organisation() async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Org").get();
    list = querySnapshot.docs;
    print(list);
    list.forEach((data) => print(data));
  }
```

Update

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Org").get();
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshots) {
      if (snapshots.connectionState == ConnectionState.active &&
          snapshots.hasData) {
        print(snapshots.data);
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshots.docs.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
            Map data= doc.data;//This is your data
            return Text(
              data.toString(),
            );
          },
        );
      } else {
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Call other methods after super.initState()

Comment: No,that dosent help. It still return instance and not the value

Comment: Please upvote and accept this as the answer if it helped :)

Comment: That didn't help either.

Comment: I think you'll have to do dome minor changes in the builder of the Streambuilder to make it work

Comment: But this displays the listview and i want to store the documents in a List so that i can display in dropdown